# Qt Opengl How to change quternion rotation point?

Tags: python-3.x, qt, opengl, pyside2, pyopengl

I'm trying to implement a rotaion around a point. The problem is: the rotation point doesn't change when I pan a camera. I've already found some useful info about changing the rotation point by converting Quaternion to a rotation matrix and multiply with transformation matrices like `T(x, y,z) * R(q) * T(-x, -y, -z)`, but i don't use any of them. All transformations performed on a single `QMatrix4x4` using `rotate` and `lookAt` methods. Are there any other solutions available?

Here's my camera class:

```py
class PlyViewportCamera:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__projectionMatrix = QMatrix4x4()
        self.__viewMatrix = QMatrix4x4()

        self.__clipRange = (0.1, 1000.0)
        self.__fov = 45

        self.__camEye = QVector3D(0.0, 5.0, -10.0)
        self.__camTarget = QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        self.__camUp = QVector3D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

        self.__viewRotation = QQuaternion()
        self.__xRotation = QQuaternion()
        self.__yRotation = QQuaternion()

    def __rotateX(self, rotation: QQuaternion):
        self.__xRotation = rotation * self.__xRotation
        self.__viewRotation = self.__xRotation * self.__yRotation
        self.__viewRotation.normalize()

    def __rotateY(self, rotation: QQuaternion):
        self.__yRotation = rotation * self.__yRotation
        self.__viewRotation = self.__xRotation * self.__yRotation
        self.__viewRotation.normalize()

    def rotate(self, p_start: QVector2D, p_end: QVector2D):
        prev_rotation = self.__viewRotation
        div_factor = 10
        diff = p_end - p_start
        angle_x = diff.y() / div_factor
        angle_y = diff.x() / div_factor
        self.__rotateX(QQuaternion.fromAxisAndAngle(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, angle_x))
        self.__rotateY(QQuaternion.fromAxisAndAngle(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, angle_y))
        self.__viewRotation = QQuaternion.slerp(prev_rotation, self.__viewRotation, 0.6)
        self.__viewRotation.normalize()

    def pan(self, start: QVector2D, end:QVector2D):
        delta = end - start
        transform = QVector3D(delta.x() / 50, delta.y() / 50, 0.0)
        self.__camEye += transform
        self.__camTarget += transform

    def updateCamera(self):
        self.__viewMatrix.setToIdentity()
        self.__viewMatrix.lookAt(self.__camEye, self.__camTarget, self.__camUp)
        self.__viewMatrix.rotate(self.__viewRotation)

    def setProjection(self, w: int, h: int):
        aspect_ratio = w / h
        self.__projectionMatrix.setToIdentity()
        self.__projectionMatrix.perspective(self.__fov, aspect_ratio, *self.__clipRange)

    @property
    def projectionMatrix(self):
        return self.__projectionMatrix

    @property
    def viewMatrix(self):
        return self.__viewMatrix
```

Comment: *"but i don't use any of them"* - Why? *"Are there any other solutions available?"* - No. A quaternion cannot represent a translation. You have to use a 4x4 matrix. Rotation around a pivot: `T(pivot) * R * T(-pivot)`

Comment: @Rabbid76, ok, thanks! The problem is, that I use ``lookAt`` function to correctly position a camera and all transformations has been done via passing changed ``camEye`` and ``camTarget`` vectors. Can we say, that a matrix produced by a ``lookAt`` is a transformation matrix? If I perform roation on it and call  ``lookAt`` with negative vectors, then it ends up with weird rotation results.